# Jest Mock Await fetch

Tags: ts-jest

I am trying to mock await fetch function following some articles but am having difficulty in being able to successfully mock

In my class, I have a function as so:

```
import createFetch from '@vercel/fetch';
import * as nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';
const fetch = createFetch(nodeFetch);
const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require('url');

export async function functionToTest(authToken,offset,limit,dateFrom, dateTo, retries= 2):Promise<any> {
  const logger = AppLogger.instance();
  let endpoint = new URL(config.endpoint);
  let params = {
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit,
    date_from: dateFrom,
    date_to: dateTo
  };
  endpoint.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
  let stringUrl = endpoint.toString();

  try {
    const response = await fetch(stringUrl, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization:authToken},
    });
}
```

My test file:

```
jest.mock('node-fetch');
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const {Response} = jest.requireActual('node-fetch');


test('test1', async () => {
    const downloadDocumentData = { data: {} };
    const getDocList = new Response(JSON.stringify(downloadDocumentData));
    fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve(getDocList));
    const userId = await functionToTest("1234", null, null, null, null);

    // expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://website.com/users', {
    //     method: 'POST',
    // });
    expect(userId).toBe('4');
});
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: opts.headers.get is not a function
```

in the file vercel/fetch/index.js:52:17 and upon examining that file, seems headers object is empty. Do I need to mock createFetch function somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to that approach working so I went with msw https://mswjs.io/ instead and it worked seamlessly afterwards.